# JQuery.ajax() behaving strangly or am I missing something?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

**EDIT:** It's about synchronization, the ajax call is asynchronous so it doesn't block the execution of code.

I have a JavaScript code that use JQuery.ajax() to upload an user supplied file, and if successful submits the form otherwise shows an error and stops the form from being submitted.

I have placed alert(); at all the important places to keep an eye on the flow of the code.The problem is the alerts are not showing up the way I was expecting and everything is messed up.

If the ajax call is successful first we should see alert('1'), if file upload is successful we should see alert('2') otherwise we should see alert('3'), if the ajax call failed for some reason we should see alert('4') and in the end we should see alert('5');

But in reality the alerts are showing like this :

```
alert('5')
alert('4')
alert('5')
And the alert('4') shows even before alert('5') goes away(without doing anything).
```

What am I missing ?

The file is getting uploaded but the result is not returning in the success function of the code.

JavaScript

```
var files;

$( document ).ready (   function (  ) { $ ( '#user_file' ).on ( 'change', prepareUpload ); }

function prepareUpload ( event ) { files = event.target.files; }

$( 'myform' ).submit( function ( event ) 
{
    var gender = $ ( 'input[name=gender_group]:checked', 'myform' ).val (  );

    var data = new FormData (  );
    data.append ( 'userfile', files [ 0 ] ); 
    data.append ( 'gender', gender ); 
    data.append ( 'ajaxUpload', 'true' );
    $returnvalue = false;

    $.ajax ( {

    method : 'POST', url : scriptUrl, data : data, cache : false, processData: false, contentType: false, dataType : 'json',
    success : function ( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) { 
        alert ( '1' );
        if ( typeof data.error === 'undefined' )
        {
            alert ( '2' ); $returnvalue = true;
        }
        else
        {
        alert ( '3' ); $returnvalue = false;
        }
    },
    error : function ( xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError ) {
        alert ( '4' ); $returnvalue = false;
    }

    });

    alert ( '5' ); return $returnvalue;

}
```

Controller

```
if (  $this->input->post ( 'gender' ) && $this->input->post ( 'ajaxUpload' )  )
{
    $this->load->model ( 'My_model' );
    echo json_encode (  $this->My_model>do_upload (  )  );
}
```

Model (My_model)

```
public function do_upload (  ) {
    $this->load->library ( 'upload' );
    $data = array (  );

    // The cofiguration for the upload call is saved in a config file - config/upload.php
    if (  ! $this->upload->do_upload (   )  ){
        $data [ 'error' ] = 'true';
    } else {         
        $data [ 'screen_name' ] = $screen_name;      
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: You are not define `scriptUrl` in your code and also check browser console for errors!!

Comment: ajax is asynchronous so alert 5 will be called before alert 4 if the processing of the ajax call takes  longer than the processing of the rest of the js before getting to the alert 5 from the start of the ajax.  Also if you return true / false from your ajax call top stop / allow the form to be submitted, it won't work

Comment: @Pete So setting a variable with true or false inside the ajax call and returning that value in the end should work, right ? Also can you please look at the code one more time and see why am I getting parseerror on the ajax call ?

Comment: @StudentX, sorry was in a meeting.  If you set the variable in the ajax, unless you make the ajax call synchronous, then trying to return it after will also have the same problem that it may not be set by the time you return it. The callback functions of the ajax is where you should be running any scripts you want to occur after the ajax call has finished.  You may want to use the [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) as this will still work inside your ajax call.  You would only use this in the cases of 3 and 4 (where you are trying to return false)